# How can we manually define topic partition and replication in kafka-conect distribution mode

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using sql-server kafka-connect and debezium to monitor sql server database, but when I publish and run my worker, the topic already is created with the name {server_name}.{schema_name}.{table_name} with default partitions=1 & replication=1, even when I specify two brokers in the "bootstrap.servers" parameter. How can I manually change the partition and replication for the table topics, or maybe specify beforehand in the worker/connector configuration? Also, different topics may have different partitions and replication.

Comment: Try changing topic creation broker settings, as their default values are set to partitions =1 and replication-factor = 1.

Comment: but that would save these parameters for all topics, which should rather vary for different topics @FatemaSagar

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options:

1. You can create the topics for each table before starting debezium connector with your required number of partitions & replication factor. This is possible as the database server, schema and table names are known (specified in configuration).
2. Even when the connector is running, simply modify the topic to increase number of partitions & replication factor. Eg.

   ```
   ./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic server.schema.table --partitions 5
   ```

   Do note that all the messages before this will be in one partition, while the new records will be distributed (based on the kafka key hashing).

Answer (score 1):

this docs https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/install.html#_configuring_debezium_topics describes how to configure the topics.

Please bear in ming that when topics are autocreated (this is Kafka broker setting) then they uses default topic settings from Kafka broker.

So you should either create them in advance manually, or change Kafka broker defaults or use `kafka-topics.sh` tool to change the replication.